# How do I dynamically create methods for Django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have been studying **Python** for several months and for the first time I got stumped. I have a sample **Django** code like this:

```
class SomeOptions(models.Model):
    FIRST = 1
    SECOND = 2
    THIRD = 3

    @classmethod
    def get_first(cls):
        return SomeOptions.objects.get(pk=cls.FIRST)

    @classmethod
    def get_second(cls):
        return SomeOptions.objects.get(pk=cls.SECOND)

    @classmethod
    def get_third(cls):
        return SomeOptions.objects.get(pk=cls.THIRD)
```

It looks disgusting. But it works exactly the way I want it to.

```
SomeOptions.get_first()
>> 'Some data from db'
```

I want to remove these methods and make them get generated dynamically. I even managed to do it this way:

```
class Dispatcher(object):

    def __init__(self, model, method_name):
        self.model = model
        self.method_name = method_name

    def __call__(self):
        return self.get_required_attribute_value()

    def get_required_attribute_value(self):
        required_attribute_name = self.get_required_attribute_name()
        required_attribute_value = getattr(self.model, required_attribute_name)
        value_from_database = self.model.objects.get(pk=required_attribute_value)
        return value_from_database

    def get_required_attribute_name(self):
        _, required_attribute_name = self.method_name.split('_')
        return required_attribute_name.upper()


class SomeOptions(models.Model):
    FIRST = 1
    SECOND = 2
    THIRD = 3

    @classmethod
    def __getattr__(cls, attr):
        return Dispatcher(cls, attr)
```

I got more code, but the most important thing is that the **Dispatcher** class is universal and can be used for any model.

The problem is this:

```
SomeOptions().get_first()
>> 'Some data from db'

SomeOptions.get_first()
>> AttributeError: type object 'SomeOptions' has no attribute 'get_first'
```

How can I get the code to work without creating a **SomeOptions()** object?

Sorry for poor English :(

Comment: There's no need for such an interface - Django already provides a large amount of methods for retrieving and modifying data in its ORM.

Comment: Yea, but there is a test for job :( Full text:
'How can you ensure that the interface for working with the SomeOptions model is not changed (i.e. it was possible to write, for example, SomeOptions.get_first()), but in
the description of the SomeOptions model would not have to declaratively describe each method get_first, get_second, thus getting rid of the same type of code.

Comment: Why not using the ORM the usual way, and also create tests for it using unit tests?